# Calculate the quotient groups and classify $\mathbb{Z^3}/(1, 1, 1)$ - Fraleigh p. 151 15.8

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I tried to start like [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518572/calculate-the-factor-group-mathbbz-4-times-mathbbz-6-langle0-2-ran). I fill in the sizes first. $\mathbb{Z}$ is an infinite group hence $\mathbb{Z^3}$ is too. $\left|\dfrac{\mathbb{Z^3}}{<(1, 1, 1)>}\right| = \dfrac{|\mathbb{Z^3}|}{|<(1, 1, 1)> \in \mathbb{Z^3} |} = \frac{\infty}{\infty}$. $\color{darkred}{ \text{ (1.)  What did I bungle here?   } }$

(1.) Now I tried http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=355789 but I'm confounded. Can someone please flesh out all the steps? Can this be done without fundamental theorem of finitely generatedabelian groups ?

(2.) What's the intuition, by means of the [last paragraph here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/91022)?

---

**Questions on Christoph Pegel's answer:**  **I deleted my original try.**

> I'm not sure why you want to calculate the order of the quotient first, but for infinite groups you can not just divide the orders. For example $\left|\mathbb Z\big/2\mathbb Z\right|=2$ while $\left|\mathbb Z\right|=\left|2\mathbb Z\right|=\infty$.
>
> Now let's look at $\mathbb Z^3\big/ H$ where $H=\langle\left(1,1,1\right)\rangle$. The idea is that you can always make the first coordinate $0$ by adding or substracting $(1,1,1)$ multiple times. To be precise:
>   $$
> (x,y,z) - x\cdot(1,1,1) = (x,y,z) - (x,x,x) = (0, y-x, z-x).
> $$

**Update** (3.) I understand this proves every coset has a representative of the form $(0,y,z).$
Hence you're authorized to drop the generator $(1, 0, 0) \in \mathbb{Z}_3$.

But before you proved this, how do you envisage and envision this hinge/'key observation'? This feels magical. What induced you to make the first coordinate $0$ by subtracting $(1, 1, 1)$ $x$ times?

> So for all cosets $[(x,y,z)]\in \mathbb Z^3\big/ H$ you have $[(x,y,z)] = [(0, y-x, z-x)]$ in the quotient. Every coset has a representative with $0$ in the first coordinate.
>
> Now can a coset have multiple representatives of this form? Assume $$
> (0,y,z)H=(0,y',z')H \iff \quad
> (0,y,z) - (0,y',z') = (\color{dodgerblue}0, \color{green}{y-y'}, \color{red}{z-z'}) \qquad \qquad \in H = \langle(1,1,1)\rangle.
> $$
>   All elements in H = $< (1, 1, 1) > = k(1, 1, 1) = (\color{dodgerblue}k,\color{green}k,\color{red}k) $ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
>   Equate component-wise to induce:
>   $\color{dodgerblue}{k = 0}, \color{green}{y - y' = k}, \color{red}{z -z' = k}.$
>   Substitute $\color{dodgerblue}{k = 0}$ to induce: 
>   $\implies \color{green}{y - y' = 0}, \color{red}{z -z' = 0}$.
>   Thus $y=y'$ and $z=z'$ and the representatives are equal.

(4.) What do your square brackets mean? Are they my curly ones $\{$?

> To summarize what we know so far:
>   Every coset in $\mathbb Z^3\big/ H$ has exactly one representative of the form $(0,y,z)$.
>
> This gives a bijective map $
> \begin{align*}
> \Phi : \mathbb Z^2 &\longrightarrow \mathbb Z^3\big/ H, \\
> (y,z) &\longmapsto [(0,y,z)].
> \end{align*}$

(5.) Can you please unfold where this bijective function magically sprang from?

> Now you can easily show this map is a homomorphism, so <s>indeed</s>
>   (My original post had the answer) $\mathbb Z^3\big/ H \cong \mathbb Z^2$.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you want to calculate the order of the quotient first, but for infinite groups you can not just divide the orders. For example $\left|\mathbb Z\big/2\mathbb Z\right|=2$ while $\left|\mathbb Z\right|=\left|2\mathbb Z\right|=\infty$.

Now let's look at $\mathbb Z^3\big/ H$ where $H=\langle\left(1,1,1\right)\rangle$. The idea is that you can always make the first coordinate $0$ by adding or substracting $(1,1,1)$ multiple times. To be precise:
$$
(x,y,z) - x\cdot(1,1,1) = (x,y,z) - (x,x,x) = (0, y-x, z-x).
$$
So for all cosets $[(x,y,z)]\in \mathbb Z^3\big/ H$ you have $[(x,y,z)] = [(0, y-x, z-x)]$ in the quotient.
Every coset has a representative with $0$ in the first coordinate.

Now can a coset have multiple representatives of this form? Assume $[(0,y,z)]=[(0,y',z')]$, then
$$
(0,y,z) - (0,y',z') = (0, y-y', z-z') \in H = \langle(1,1,1)\rangle.
$$
All elements in $H$ are of the form $(k,k,k)$ for some $k\in \mathbb Z$, so from $(0, y-y', z-z') \in H$ it follows that $y-y'=0$ and $z-z'=0$ since the first coordinate is $0$. Thus $y=y'$ and $z=z'$ and the representatives are equal.

To summarize what we know so far:
Every coset in $\mathbb Z^3\big/ H$ has exactly one representative of the form $(0,y,z)$.

This gives a bijective map
\begin{align*}
\Phi : \mathbb Z^2 &\longrightarrow \mathbb Z^3\big/ H, \\
(y,z) &\longmapsto [(0,y,z)].
\end{align*}

Now you can easily show this map is a homomorphism, so indeed $\mathbb Z^3\big/ H \cong \mathbb Z^2$.

**Regarding your questions:**

> (3.) Can you please flesh out this idea? Why do we want the first coordinate 0?
>   This looks like the hinge. I'm perplexed where this loomed from.

This is indeed the key observation. While $\mathbb Z^3$ is generated by the **3 generators** $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$, we can generate $\mathbb Z^3\big/H$ by the **2 generators** $[(0,1,0)]$ and $[(0,0,1)]$, since (as I showed) every coset has a representative of the form $(0,y,z)$. So we can drop a generator, which suggests that our quotient is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^2$ (or a quotient of that).

> (4.) What do your square brackets mean? Are they my curly ones {?

No, the curly ones are always sets. The square brackets denote cosets:
$$
[(x,y,z)] := (x,y,z) + H.
$$

> (5.) Can you please unfold where this bijective function magically sprang from?

It's the whole idea of the proof. We showed that we only need the two generators $[(0,1,0)], [(0,0,1)]$. So let's take $\mathbb Z^2$ and map it's two generators $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$ to the two of $\mathbb Z^3\big/H$ and we get an isomorphism!

Indeed if we have *any* abelian group $G$ generated by 2 elements $G=\langle a,b\rangle$ we get an epimorphism by
\begin{align}
\Phi: \mathbb Z^2 &\longrightarrow G,\\
(x,y) &\longmapsto x\cdot a + b\cdot y.
\end{align}
Try to prove this! Then, by the homomorphism theorem, $\mathbb Z^2/\ker\Phi\cong G$. In our case $\Phi$ is injective so $\ker\Phi=\{(0,0)\}$ and thus $\mathbb Z^2\cong G$.

> **Update** (3.) I understand this proves every coset has a representative of the form (0,y,z).
>   Hence you're authorized to drop the generator (1,0,0)∈ℤ3.
>
> But before you proved this, how do you envisage and envision this hinge/'key observation'? This feels magical. What induced you to make the first coordinate 0 by subtracting (1,1,1) x times?

It's an idea, thats very different from magic. And as you see, this idea turns out just fine. Maybe start with $\mathbb Z^3\big/\langle(1,0,0)\rangle$ which gives you $[(x,y,z)]=[(0,y,z)]$ immediatly, since we just modded out a generator. For $\mathbb Z^3\big/ H$ we are in a similar situation: We can generate $\mathbb Z^3$ by $(1,1,1)$, $(0,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$ (check this!), modding out one of these leaves us with the other two.

> (2.) What's the intuition, by means of the [last paragraph here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/91022)?

When you look at the quotient $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z^6\big/\langle(1,2)\rangle$ you get the relation $[(1,2)]=[(0,0)]$ which you could also write as $[(1,0)]=[(0,-2)]=[(0,4)]$. Since $(0,4)$ has order $3$, the order of $[(1,0)]$ in the quotient must divide $3$ as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Upvoted. Can you please notify me about my updated (3)? I'm still perplexed. Can you please notify me if you answered (2)? I might've missed it. Please answer in your answer and not in comments. I’ll upvote your other posts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm still perplexed about (3.). How do you envisage and envision to mod out a generator, before calculating anything? I don't understand where this 'key observation' looms from? Please answer in your answer and not in comments.